# How to make a function to play only on the home page?

Tags: css, javascript

How can I make the 2 functions setTimeOut that are showing the element with id="mess" and then hiding it, run only on the home page, so that if the user goes to another page, it doesnt run again. I know the code doesnt work here. It is working on a website on wordpress with elementor. Thank you!

```
<div id="cursorz">
  <div class="message" id="mess">Look at you! You look beautiful today!</div>
</div>

@media only screen and (min-width: 1367px) {
body {cursor:none;}
.message {
width: 20em;
height: 5em;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid black;
color: white;
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 2em;
border-radius: 20px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: baseline;
transition: all 2s ease;
z-index: 2;
display: none;
}

.show {
 display: block;
}

#cursorz {
z-index:1000000;
pointer-events: none;
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
will-change: transform;
background: #f1f1f1;
position: absolute;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
border-radius: 50%;

}


}

<script type="text/javascript">
const cursorz = document.getElementById("cursorz");
const moveCursor = event => {
const cursorWidth = cursorz.offsetWidth / 2;
cursorz.style.left = event.pageX - cursorWidth + "px";
cursorz.style.top = event.pageY - cursorWidth + "px";
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCursor);

setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('mess').classList.add('show');
 }, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('mess').classList.remove('show');
   }, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: where is the code in your question located?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing a lot of context from your question. If you are only asking how to execute a script on the homepage (and not on other pages), you can use the `is_front_page()` function. You can wrap your entire script in an `if statement`, like below:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>

YOUR SCRIPT HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```

Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/ for more detailed information about this function.

**EDIT**

To only show the **message** on the front page, but keep the rest of the code on all other pages, you can simply wrap the message part in your conditional. Check out below:

```
<div id="cursorz">

  <?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>

    <div class="message" id="mess">Look at you! You look beautiful today!</div>

  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Yes, I only want to execute the code on the front page. But here is the thing that I don't understand: How can I wrap only this part of the code that is responsible for the message appearance? I basically want to have the custom mouse everywhere, but the message "Look at you! You look beautiful today!" to appear only when the user is on the front page. Here is the site: https://simplifixstudio.com/

Comment: Please check out my edited answer. You can simple wrap the conditional around your message div.

Comment: Here is how I pasted the code:
<div id="cursorz">
 <?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
  <div class="message" id="mess">Look at you! You look beautiful today!</div>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>

I am pasting it in the Elementor CustomCode area but it's telling me that "Special characters must be escaped : [>] and [<]" and the code doesn't seem to work. It's still showing on all other pages.

Comment: I just read elementor doesnt allow php code.. Is it possible to do it with JS?

Comment: Ah, you're pasting the code inside Elementor. In the future, please include this information in your question. That is some crucial information. To answer your question, it is possible to do this in JS. Just alter your script to run only if your body has a class of 'home'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to do that!

Comment: I did it!! I wrapped the code around this:

if (document.body.classList.contains('home')) {

}
Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome!